# libc include guards not respecting source type parameter changes

Tags: c, libc

### Question

If I include `time.h`, change a "source type parameter" and re-include that header, shouldn't it add in those new definitions? I understand that this is happening due to include guards. My question is: is this a bug in libc? Shouldn't it be able to handle this?

```
#include <time.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <time.h>

static struct timespec t;
```

Error message:

```
example.c:5:24: error: storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known
    5 | static struct timespec t;
      |                        ^
```

### Background

I discovered this behavior building a Python extension while compiling with `-std=c99`. If I included standard libraries before I included `Python.h` I would get compilation errors due to missing definitions of POSIX functionality. If I moved the `Python.h` include before everything else, all was fine. Of course compiling with `-std=gnu99` works as well. But I wanted to get to the bottom of why the error was occurring and distilled it down to the above code sample.

Which begs another question. If the above behavior isn't a bug, is setting `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and similar source type parameters in a header considered bad practice? Should Python remove the setting of that parameter in their headers and instead require users to define it during compilation, or use `std=gnu99`?

Comment: *"If I include time.h, change a "source type parameter" and re-include that header, shouldn't it add in those new definitions?"* No, quite the contrary, actually. The guards are there so that you don't declare something a second time. So the "old" definitions are the ones that stay, they don't get overwritten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're calling "source type parameters" are called feature test macros, and they are specifically required to be defined before inclusion of **any** standard header if they are defined at all.

This is specified in [XSH 2.2.1 POSIX.1 Symbols](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01):

> A POSIX-conforming application shall ensure that the feature test macro _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined before inclusion of any header.
>
> ...
>
> An XSI-conforming application shall ensure that the feature test macro _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined with the value 700 before inclusion of any header.

The [Linux man page for `feature-test-macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) also clearly states this requirement for the standard ones and its extensions:

> NOTE: In order to be effective, a feature test macro *must be defined before including any header files*

You cannot redefine and reinclude headers to change things, and in fact defining or undefining/redefining them between headers (even different, seemingly unrelated headers) may completely break things.

Comment: So this means that it is likely Python documentation lacking. They should state that Python depends upon POSIX standards and extension modules should be compiled with `-std=gnu99` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of Python documentation. If you want to compile with `-std=c99` but want POSIX or further functionality, you need to use FTMs to get it. This is documented in GCC I think. The preferred way is adding the proper `-D` wherever you added `-std=c99` (in `CFLAGS`), not editing sources. Then you ensure it's defined before any header is included.

Comment: It is a matter of documentation. I am not using POSIX, Python is, and it *assumes* it is there. Because there was no documentation stating otherwise, I thought using C99 and reordering includes was acceptable, it is not.

Comment: I see. Then yes, Python should document that you need to compile module sources using the Python headers/interfaces with appropriate FTMs to make POSIX baseline (or XSI, or whatever) functionality available and mention that they need to be defined at top of files or via `-D`.